# Como fazer cadastro de um CPT irem para uma página específica?

Tags: wordpress

Procurar mas não descobri como fazer com que os dados de um CPT de cadastro de jogador (que incluem nome, foto e telefone), vão para a página jogadores.

Ou seja quero que os dados do cadastro no (back-end, painel administrativo do WordPress) seja exibir na página jogadores (no front-end). Como fazer essa ponte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confira [Tipos de Posts Personalizados « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Tipos_de_Posts_Customizados) (o [original em inglês é mais completo](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates)) onde verá por exemplo:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Vai usar esse código dentro de páginas específicas do seu Theme trocando aquele `product` por `jogador`.

Recursos para entender a hierarquia de um Theme:

- [Template Hierarchy | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
- [The WordPress Template Hierarchy - a visualization resource](http://wphierarchy.com/)

  <kbd>[image: exemplo da hierarquia]</kbd>

Boa parte do Codex tem tradução ao português.
A nova seção [Official WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/) ainda não.

Comment: ps: o primeiro lugar para procurar é a documentação, seja trabalhando com WordPress, PHP, jQuery, Stack Overflow... se não encontrar aí, pode começar a pesquisar no resto e a escrever um pergunta para postar aqui. Ao final da pesquisa/testes, ou já resolveu ou tem uma excelente pergunta para postar ;)

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo. Seguirei seus conselhos !